# Unit testing ArcGIS Pro SDK?

Tags: unit-testing, arcgis-pro-sdk

I am wondering, if there is a possibility to unit test own code using the ArcGIs Pro 2.0 SDK. I did not find any until now, because there are plenty of static functions, classes, etc. and no interfaces, that allows faking.
Comming from ArcObject I used so far NUnit as testing framework and NSubstitute to fake com interfaces, that worked fine.

Comment: Apparently GIS developers don't write unit tests

Comment: Still 3 years later, this is a problem. See https://community.esri.com/thread/163979 and https://community.esri.com/ideas/11537